# Yii2 Console: app\models Class not found but common\models found

Tags: php, yii2

I have an Yii2 web application with 50+ model class files that are located in `/models` directory.

Now I want to run some console scripts from `/console/controllers/MyController.php` using these models but get `class app\models\ModelName not found` error, despite of `use app\models\ModelName` at the top.

If I copy a model file to `/console/models/ModelName.php` or `/common/models/ModelName.php` (and make change in use) it works alright. Is there any option to use models from /model or should I refactor the application so that both web and console use model files from `/common/models`

Comment: You could start by showing the relevant parts of your code - how **exactly** do you run these scripts? Maybe you forgot to add the autoloader?

Comment: You need to show the code, when using namespaces inline you need to use slashes in start like `\app\models\ModelName`

Comment: Sorry, it's a big system and hard to cut out the important part of code. I've tried \app\models (as my IDE suggests) but probelm seems to be that \app points to a different places depending on context (as Andry says in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using yii2-advanced build take in mind that `@app` alias is set each time depending on what part of application you are using.

If you are making a call from `frontend`, `@app` will be equal to /path/to/project-root/frontend.

If from `backend` - /path/to/project-root/backend.

`console` - /path/to/project-root/console

You may add custom alias in `/common/config/bootstrap.php`, to make your classes available from root.

For example try to add `Yii::setAlias('@root', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));` to `/common/config/bootstrap.php` and set namespace to `root/models`

**Note**: if you will try add `@app` to `bootstrap.php`, it will be automatically reassigned by framework.

**Note 2**: You may check how yii2 autoloader works in [BaseYii.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/BaseYii.php#L277)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It went better (still not perfect) with alias but as this means also rewriting lot of files, I think I'll move my model files to the existing /common/ directory - hope that works out for now.

Comment: @zuups you reassign `@app` in some different place. Like in bootstrap of some model or component. Though it may  cause unexpected results if yiisoft uses this alias